# Understand kernel task names

Tags: linux, ps, output

If I have something like this:

```
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:06   0:00 [migration/3]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:06   0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:06   0:00 [kworker/3:0H]
```

What can these numbers(`/3` or `/3:0H`) can tell me?

`man ps`, `man top` - nothing said about this.